# how to plot aggregated dataframes in seaborn in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i have a dataframe of measurements across time that contain replicates. i am trying to plot an aggregated and summarized version of this dataframe with seaborn. the data is:

```
A = pandas.DataFrame({"measurement": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                      "t": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                      "value": [10, 10.5, 10.4, 10.6, 10.01,
                                10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})
A["cond"] = "A"
B = pandas.DataFrame({"measurement": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                      "t": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                      "value": [20, 40.5, 5.4, 1.6, 1.01,
                                30, 50, 60, 4, 3]})
B["cond"] = "B"
df = pandas.concat([A, B])
```

"cond" is the condition, "measurement" are the different replicates (2 per condition), and "t" is the time dimension. to average across time in each replicate, i use `agg`:

```
x = df.groupby(["measurement", "cond"]).agg({"value": np.mean})
```

this returns a hierarchical dataframe. i want to plot these values with seaborn, to show the measurements as a distribution. this does not work:

```
sns.violinplot(x="cond", y="value", hue="cond", data=x)
```

it errors with: `ValueError: Could not interperet input 'cond'`

how can you flatten the dataframe returned by `agg` so it can be plotted with seaborn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use parameter `as_index=False` for `groupby`:

```
x = df.groupby(["measurement", "cond"], as_index=False).agg({"value": np.mean})
```

[image]

Comment: does ``as_index=False`` guarantee a flat dataframe?

Comment: Yes, it will be with one level index

Comment: It will only be a flat data frame, if you don't do multiple aggregates. For example if you did `x = df.groupby(["measurement", "cond"], as_index=False).agg({"value": [np.mean, np.sum, np.max, np.min]})`, this will generate a MultiIndex column.
Though you can make it flat by using `x.columns = x.columns.map('_'.join)`